# Define API destination with React on Production Server

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a React application which works with a REST API that is deployed on the same machine as the React application.

- The React application is deplyoed on port 80 (using Apache Http Server)
- The REST API is a Flask based application deployed on port 5000.

Currently as a workaround I set the production server to run on host X.Y.W.Z so i hard-coded the API target in the React files:

const API_HOST = 'http://X.Y.W.Z:5000'

What is the best practice to set the API destination if i want it to be the same host as the React application but on a different port? (Saw some posts about it but no-one had a solution, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367424/how-to-set-react-app-and-api-on-same-port) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51457771/reactjs-api-host-in-production) for example)

Maybe to forward the request from the React Router to the WebServer and set there a reverse proxy? How it can be configured?

On the development server i used the `proxy` attribute in the package.json (as [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0)) to forward the request - but its on the specific development server and it still should be hardcoded.

(I think that the definition should be not depended on the deployed host (tomorrow i can change to host to different server - so i should always set the API target?)

Answer (score 0):

Change API_HOST according to the node environment.

`const API_HOST = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'http://X.Y.W.Z' : 'http://X.Y.W.Z:5000';`.

And if you are using proxy for development server, then you can use specify the `API_HOST` as

`const API_HOST = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'http://X.Y.W.Z' : '';`

Comment: Hmm... it seems like it still hardcoding it, but in the package.json file. As i understand the webpack somehow inject the environment variable to the application on run time. Is there some kind of Hostname environment variable ? didn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
const API_HOST = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'http://X.Y.W.Z' : 
                                                         'http://X.Y.W.Z:5000';
```

And if you are using proxy for development server, then you can specify the API_HOST as:

```
const API_HOST = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'http://X.Y.W.Z' : '';
```